# Should I convert this getter into method?

Tags: c#, methods, properties, getter

In the past few days I've been reading about the differences betweeen properties and methods in C# and when use each. Most of the articles/questions I read says that getters should be "light" and never have large amount of logic or complex operations inside.

Right now I have a `get` that I think is on the line between property and method, so I would like to see what you all think, if I should change to method or stay with the getter.

Also any other advice is welcome :D

```
public decimal[] getPreprocData
{
    get
    {
        int i = 3;
        decimal[] data = new decimal[9];

        data[0] = (start.Value.Hour * 3600) + (start.Value.Minute * 60);
        data[1] = duration.Value;
        data[2] = flowRate.Value;

        foreach (NumericUpDown nud in gbHTF.Controls.OfType<NumericUpDown>().OrderBy(nud => nud.TabIndex))
        {
            data[i] = nud.Value;
            i++;
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: This really belongs on codereview.stackexchange

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Properties` & `Field` are generally **`Noun`** and 
`methods` & `functions` are generally **`Verb`**.

so, `getPreprocData` should be a `method`. Since it respresnt an action on instance of the object (class).

---

From  my own point of view, since your property is never making use of the `setter`, it is always better to use `method` than `property`.

*What is the point of having a property when there is nothing to set.?*

---

You property can be implemented as method as :

```
public decimal[] GetPreprocData()
{
        int i = 3;
        decimal[] data = new decimal[9];

        data[0] = (start.Value.Hour * 3600) + (start.Value.Minute * 60);
        data[1] = duration.Value;
        data[2] = flowRate.Value;

        foreach (NumericUpDown nud in gbHTF.Controls.OfType<NumericUpDown>().OrderBy(nud => nud.TabIndex))
        {
            data[i] = nud.Value;
            i++;
        }

        return preprocData;
}
```

Comment: Should definitely be a method. Not sure whether you should prefix it with "get" though. If the result is something you would always assign to something, it should have a noun for a name even though it's a method, otherwise it just reads wrong. It'd be like calling Math.Sin(), Math.GetSin(), or calling Random.Next(), Random.GetNext() and so on.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like something that should indeed be a method.

You are doing a bit of initialization, and the size of `gbHTF.Controls` is unbounded, so this *may* end up being expensive.

It is also hiding behind a property name that doesn't actually describe what you are doing - this would be better as a descriptive method.

Answer (score 0):

Convert it into a method. There's processing and business logic in there.

Generally, I'd limit properties to formatting or combining of other properties, just so you have a clear separation of concerns.